# deserialize datetime WebApi across date formats

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, date-format

I have a method on a controller that has a non nullable datetime param. Before it is sent over it is formatted one of 4 ways: MM/DD/YYYY, MM/DD/YY, DD/MM/YYYY, DD/MM/YY.

Right now the deserialization works for the first 2 formats. But not for any variation of DD/MM/YYYY. Instead I get `01/01/0001`.

Example controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public object Test(DateTime dt)
    {
```

Get valid datetime: `02/23/2016`

Get 01/01/0001: `23/02/2016`

Comment: You want to support all four input formats at once? Then tell me, is `01/02/2016` February the 1st, or January the 2nd? You can't tell them apart. Choose one format and stick to it - I suggest `yyyy-MM-dd` which is more or less standard.

Answer (score 0):

When you are posting DateTime data to the controller, then it accepts all the DateTime formats as your system's DateTime format. If posting the string is not a problem, instead of DateTime type, you can post DateTime as a string and parse it as your desired format like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public object Test(string dt)
    { 
      DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can use any DateTime format like this. And if it's not possible then you always have to stick to a specific format

Comment: please fix your grammar on all of your posts